# ffmpeg: Convert gif to video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, duration

I want to convert a gif file to a video with ffmpeg.
I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /gif/583fd7661b46d.gif -strict -2 -an -b:v 32M /gif/mp4/583fd7661b46d.avi
```

The duration of my gif in photoshop is 27 seconds, but the duration of the video "583fd7661b46d.avi" generated is 15 seconds.
How can I get the same duration of my gif in the video generated?

I execute this:

```
ffplay file.gif
```

It steel read without stoping and the "M-V" is incremented
[image]

Comment: Is the playback duration correct with `ffplay file.gif`?

Comment: I don't have the duration with ffplay (see my edit post)

Comment: Time it. ffplay will keep on going even after the file ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change the output format to .mp4, the duration becomes correct.

Or with the output avi I add the option `-vsync cfr` in my ffmpeg command.